# Using mahout to categorize items based on user similarity

Tags: hadoop, machine-learning, cluster-analysis, mahout, categorization

I have a list of tracks that play in different radios. Data is like this:

```
radio_id,track_id,times_played
1,536,1
1,3292,1
1,3294,1
2,3303,7
2,3322,1
2,3341,3
3,3365,5
3,3511,4
3,3680,1
...
```

Based on what tracks play in each radio, it is possible to know the radio genre. How to produce groups of similar radios with Mahout using this data?
I want an output similar to this:

```
group1: 1,4,67,100
group2: 2,3,5,66
...
```

Comment: What do you mean by radio genre ?

Comment: I think we can use concept similar to TDF & IDF.Since you already have station id, track and frequency so we have a matrix of frequencies. Then we can check Inverted frequencies by dividing total number of station that played that track  with total number of station. And then execute K-Means to cluster them.

Comment: @Tanveer I understood the concepts, but I still don't know how to execute it using mahout. Do you have any practical command line examples?

Comment: If your data fits into main memory (e.g. less than 32 GB for a modern machine), avoid Mahout. MapReduce only pays off when you need 100+ nodes. Otherwise, use something more efficient and simpler (but non distributed).

Comment: @Anony-Mousse are are your open source suggestions?

Comment: Try sklearn. It seems to be very fast, easy to use, and have a large community.

Comment: If you want you can execute clustering algorithm with R. It will be simple to do. You just need to create a 3 * N matrix for your dataset and can learn K-Means Over It. It is very simple. Create your matrix "m". Then > k <- 7 ## Cluster you want to produce. Then > kmeansResult <- kmeans(m3, k) And then > round(kmeansResult$centers, digits=3)

Comment: Further doing it with mahout will be little complicated. We need to prepare a vector for the input in a sequence file format. And then have code a java program to read that vector and invoke clustering algorithm. I documented what I did to try clustering on mahout may be you want to take a look:  http://mahoutwithtanveer.blogspot.in/

Comment: And if you want to do it Mahout without coding and much pain you may want to take a look at the http://prediction.io It provides an abstraction layer over Mahout. Make life easy.